# how to determine if this series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was trying to find out if the series:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n^3e^{-n} $$

converges.

I tried applying the Cauchy test,

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^3e^{-n}}=\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n^{\frac{3}{n}}e^{-1}$

but that gives an undetermined form of $[ \infty^{0}] $ which doesn't allow me to continue....

any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you try the ratio test? Usually that's easier, as it involves fewer roots.

Comment: because I have no desire of dealing with (n+1)^3

Comment: Ah. Well then, your desire to answer the question isn't great enough for it to merit your further attention.

Comment: I hardly think this is a worthy reply from a professor of mathematics...Sir

Comment: $n^{3/n}\rightarrow1$.

Comment: I'm not a professor of mathematics. I used to be. But if you don't want to do the work necessary to get you to the answer, then it's your choice.

Comment: Why does the indeterminate form $\infty^0$ prevent you from continuing?  Just take the log of the limit, then power by $e$ at the end.

Comment: @SimpleArt: That's indeed the best way to continue once we have proven the properties of $\exp,\ln$. But see my answer for a bare-hands proof that only uses basic arithmetic for positive integer $k$-th roots!

Answer (score 3):

Use a ratio test :$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| \frac { { a }_{ n+1 } }{ { a }_{ n } }  \right| = } \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| \frac { { \left( n+1 \right)  }^{ 3 }{ e }^{ -\left( n+1 \right)  } }{ { n }^{ 3 }{ e }^{ -n } }  \right| =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \left| \frac { { \left( n+1 \right)  }^{ 3 } }{ e{ n }^{ 3 } }  \right|  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ e } <1$$
so it converges

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can be continued. As mentioned in the comments $n^{3/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Note that this follows if we can prove $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Here is an elementary proof using only the (generalized) squeeze theorem and basic algebra.

Take any real $ε > 0$, and let $c \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/2^c \le ε$.   [This arises from what we need below.]

As $n \to \infty$:

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k \le n \le 2^{k+1}$.

Then $k \to \infty$   [since $2^k \ge n/2 \to \infty$].

Let $d = k-c$.

Thus $n^{1/n} \le (2^{k+1})^{1/2^k} \le 2^{(2d+1)/2^{c+d}} \le 2^{1/2^c}$ (eventually)   [since $c \le d$ and $2d+1 \le 2^d$].

Also $2^{1/2^c} \le 1+1/2^c \le 1+ε$.

Thus $1 \le n^{1/n} \le 1+ε$.

Therefore by the squeeze theorem $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: This is more for fun, since it is better to first define and prove properties of the exponential function so that we can directly compute $n^{1/n} = \exp(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}) \to 1$ because $\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. However, this latter fact is still best proven by exactly the same technique, the crucial step being $\ln(n)/n \le \ln(2) (k+1) / 2^k \le \ln(2) (2d+1)/2^{c+d} \le \ln(2) / 2^c$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

1. $\lim n^k e^{-n} = 0$ for all $k$
2. $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent

Answer (score 0):

This is a positive series. Let $u_n = n^3 e^{-n}$ such that the given series is $\sum u_n$. One has :

$$ \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \frac{(n+1)^3}{e^{n+1}} \times \frac{e^n}{n^3}  \xrightarrow[n \longrightarrow \infty]{} \frac{1}{e}$$

By the ratio test, the series $\sum n^3 e^{-n}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This series can be summed exactly.

Write $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n = (1-x)^{-1}$$ which converges absolutely for $|x|<1$. Note that your series can be written in terms of various derivatives $f^{(k)}(e^{-1})$, all of which converge similarly.

Details left to the reader.